# Use date in Excel cell in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

How do I connect the Excel cell with the date to the SQL Query? I use Power Query. The Database is SQL Server.Please Help me.

Example of Query:

```
Select Account, Date
From Accountdate
Where Date = "Value in Excel cell"
```

Comment: You tagged VBA, are you doing this in Excel to fill a data set OR are you doing this in SSMS on a Server?

Comment: In Excel with Power Query.

Comment: If you are querying SQL then enclose the date value in single quotes. If you are using an Access database, enclose the date in `#` signs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type a value into an Excel cell
2. Keep that cell selected. From the Power Query ribbon choose From Table.
3. Uncheck My Table Has Headers before clicking OK.
4. In the Power Query Query Editor, right click on that single value which you entered before and choose Drill Down
5. Click Apply & Close
6. In the Power Query, choose From SQL
7. Connect to your data source (don't worry about using the parameter yet.)
8. Once you're in the Query Editor with the correct SQL table being shown, choose the column you want to filter by your parameter. Go ahead and do a filter using the filter dropdown. Now change the formula bar and replace the number that you filtered by with the name of the query that you created in Step 5. That query by default will be called Table1 so your query in this step might look something like this: = Table.SelectRows(dbo_MySqlTable, each [ID] > Table1)
9. You will probably get a prompt asking you to classify the permissions to apply to each data source to make sure there are no security leaks. Once you've done that, click OK.
10. Click Apply & Close.

Comment: I will try this!